# Browser like experience on a .Net Server

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

I want to generate a leaflet map on a .Net server. Currently am aware that this i only possible on the browser. I want it server server side so that i can re-generate automatically later and export it to various formats for a report

- Are there tools that I can integrate with my .Net project to give 
  me a  browser  like experience on the server

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to server side rendering  of js and css on DOM  files with chromium.
Chrome can be run as headless providing the capability to render in the backend without it's UI. There's a library than can be used to drive chromium call peppetteer for Node js
and PuppeteerSharp for .Net. Under .Net u can get it as Nuget Package and as for Node js its on npm .

https://github.com/kblok/puppeteer-sharp  for PuppeteerSharp